# How can i connect RFID reader EM-18 Module with android system?

Tags: android, rfid

hey i am dealing with RFID project along with android application.I have tried rfid reader connection with desktop application which is done in vb.net. But now for integrating android application i need to connect my RFID reader with android phone can anyone help me for that???

Comment: How are you physically connecting from the PC?  Ethernet, serial, USB, etc...?

Comment: its serial USB connector

Comment: I'm using a PROLIFIC SERIAL to USB connector...

Answer (score 0):

It is not so easy. It requires you have some electrotechnical skills. Probably you have.

Firstly, I assume you want to connect it via USB. The EM-18 reader is not build to connect via USB so you have to use USB to RS232 converter. 
Try some cable or use a eg. some modules or chips from [FTDIChips](http://www.ftdichip.com/).

Also you can use microprocessors from ATMEL, MICROCHIP ...etc with USB interface. But requires strong programming skills (USB firmaware, communication firmaware) although most of this is already build.

This is a innevitable minimum what I wrote. It is only an interconnection between USB and EM-18.

Android device has to be able to work as USB Host.
If you are going to use FTDI chips you will need rooted device and modified kernel with a FTDI driver. Everything is on [FTDIChips](http://www.ftdichip.com/). Examples, drivers, firmwares, tutorials....

The second choice (doesnt require rooted device or special drivers, but you have to handle whole communication (RAW), but in EM-18 there is nothing so special) is to build own converter as easy as possible with microprocessor from ATMEL or MICROCHIP. The minimum firmware for USB bus communication is already developed and is downlodable for the concrete processor. Everything you will need is develop code for reading an ID from RFID card and call function to send via USB to USB HOST (Android device(activity)). Easilly told.
Android activity should be able to enumerate your USB (via VID/PID) device and read some data from your USB device.
Also you should consider to represent your device as HID compliant. Look for it on the web.
It is probably thew best choice for your device(RFID reader). But it does not mean you will avoid the principle of second choice. :-)

Look at the USB host API [android.hardware.usb](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/package-summary.html).
I hope this info is helpfull and give you a startpoint.

Comment: I have connected the serial port to a usb port using PROLIFIC SERIAL TO USB converter.I am able to get signals from RFID.But I cant distinguish the data packets from other serial datas from it.